# How to configure JHipster microservice with cloudfoundry UAA

Tags: jhipster, cloud-foundry

Is there a way to configure `JHipster` microservice application with the `Cloudfoundry UAA`?

During generation of microservice application with `Yeoman JHipster generator` it gives us an option to select UAA application provided by JHipster for authentication. However I don't want to use UAA application provided by JHipster.

I have other applications in cloudfoundry which use UAA instance provided by Cloudfoundry. So I want to configure the same with JHipster.

Any help is appreciated.